# How do I write data to an existing file in Excel using Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I used the following code to read data in file_1 then write that to a new file_2.

```
import pandas as pd
inventory = pd.read_excel('file_1.xlsx', skiprows=3)
inventory.to_excel('file_2.xlsx')
```

file_2 is a newly created file each time. How do I write the data to specific tab in an existing file without clearing out other tabs that contain data?

Answer (score 1):

`ExcelWriter` can be used to append to an existing Excel file using  `mode='a'`. Specify the sheet name with the `sheet_name` parameter.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('file_2.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:  
    inventory.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
```

Comment: Thank you. The only part I don't understand is how it knows how to find file_2 with that code.

Comment: The file will be written to the default working directory unless otherwise specified.

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you. When I do that it keeps creating a new sheet. Is there a way to have it put the data in an existing sheet?